# Доступ к файлу

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, файлы, .net

На сайте написанный на asp.net, реализацию ,что пользователя который вводить 3 раза неправильно пароль ,хоть для не существующего аккаунта,бросаю в блок лист(файл на сервере).

```
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(GetBlockListPath());
    sw.WriteLine(outsideIp + "$" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    sw.Close();
```

меня интересует, если одновременно несколько пользователей записать в файл на сервере,не вызовет ли это конфликт?То есть, если открыть этот файл для одного пользователя ,не вызовет ли ошибку, если для другого пользователя открыть открытый файл?

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходим функционал логгера. Городить свой велосипед не нужно, ибо он заведомо проигрывает любым уже написанным логгерам.
Подключите NuGet-пакет [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) или [NLog](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

Сбрасывать логи в файл в многопользовательской системе не самый лучший выбор, я бы посоветовал таки писать в базу.

Или как альтерьнатива - заюзать [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) - он поддерживает множество разных фоматов.

Answer (score 0):

Новый StreamWriter не получит доступ к файлу если файл уже открыт. Выбросит исключение IOException

Comment: я об этом и думал,возможно ли это исправить?